# Infinite recursion for null ids when using @JsonIdentityInfo

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I have 2 DTO bidirectional structures `Category` and `Product` where `Product` is the many side in `one-to-many` relationship. I want to transfer them as JSON to the front-end layer by `REST`. I don't have any problems when ids are already assigned (for update operation), but I face well-known infinite recursion when ids are empty (create).

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="categoryId")
public class CategoryDTO implements Serializable {
    private Long categoryId;
    private String categoryName;
    private List<ProductDTO> products = new LinkedList<>();

    public void addProduct(ProductDTO product) {
        products.add(product);
        product.setCategory(this);
    }

    // remove synchronization method, setters, getters
}
```

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="productId")
public class ProductDTO implements Serializable {
    private Long productId;
    private String productName;
    private CategoryDTO category;

    // setters, getters
}
```

However, when I use `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference` all is fine. I receive beautiful json:

```json
{
   "categoryId":null,
   "categoryName":"category_name",
   "products": [
      {
         "productId":null,
         "productName":"product1"
      }
   ]
}
```

```
public class CategoryDTO implements Serializable {
    private Long categoryId;
    private String categoryName;

    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<ProductDTO> products = new LinkedList<>();

    public void addProduct(ProductDTO product) {
        products.add(product);
        product.setCategory(this);
    }

    // remove synchronization method, setters, getters
}
```

```
public class ProductDTO implements Serializable {
    private Long productId;
    private String productName;

    @JsonBackReference
    private CategoryDTO category;

    // setters, getters
}
```

In both examples the rest side is following:

```
@RestController
public class CategoryController {
    @GetMapping(path = "/categories")
    public ResponseEntity<CategoryDTO> fetchCategories() {
        CategoryDTO category = new CategoryDTO();
        category.setCategoryName("category_name");

        ProductDTO product1 = new ProductDTO();
        product1.setProductName("product1");

        category.addProduct(product1);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(category, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Why `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference` work, but `@JsonIdentityInfo` don't?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

`@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference` are using object instance reference, so it works, when you add `Product` to `Category`, while `@JsonIdentityInfo`is using id from value of the field.

The answer is in the class `WritableObjectId` and `BeanSerializerBase#_serializeWithObjectId(Object, JsonGenerator, SerializerProvider, boolean)`.

In other words, for non-null fields serializer remembers, that he serialized given class instance, but he cannot do that for null fields. You can see that, when you hit endpoint `/categories`. Before the connection is interrupted, infinite JSON is generated.

Please someone correct me, if I'm wrong.

**NOTE:** Imo you should just remove field `private CategoryDTO category` or change it to `private Long categoryId` and you will get rid of any annotation :D Also you won't have any problem with infinite recursion.